# how to align facebook plugin

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like

I'm using facebook Like Button plugin

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="xyz.com" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="600" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

I want it to align at right of the page. Any CSS code for doing this or any other technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a style tag to float it right, so that you don't have to worry about it. Place it before your paragraphs at the top of the page and it will float to the right of that paragraph. I added a margin of 10px so that text will not run right next to it.

Let me know if that helps.

```
<div style="float: right; margin: 10px;" class="fb-like" data-href="xyz.com" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="600" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Type `<center>` at the beginning of your code block, and `</center>` at the end of your code block.

Worked for me

Comment: The `<center>` tag is not supported in HTML5. Use _CSS_ instead.

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Answering Questions Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you